# Override layout files of a library in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

So in my project, we are overriding a preferences layout file - `preference_category_material.xml` from `androidx.preference:preference` library.

Our new code of `preference_category_material.xml` looks something like this

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="UnusedResources"
    android:id="@android:id/textView"
    ...
    />
```

The TextView is the root and the only element in the file.

While running `./gradlew lintRelease` I am getting this error:

```
Error: Overriding @layout/preference_category_material which is marked as private in androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0. If deliberate, use tools:override="true", otherwise pick a different name. [PrivateResource]
```

I have seen a similar question, but that deals with color tags: [Override resources in library android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289717/override-resources-in-library-android)

Adding `tools:override="true"` to the TextView in our file does nothing.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="UnusedResources"
    tools:override="true"
    android:id="@android:id/textView"
    ...
    />
```

This does not solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unclear if you have seen this answer to [Override layout xml from android framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777812/295004) whose title is somewhat misnamed.

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes this might be a solution.